# Trying to understand an exercise using factorials with induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, self-learning, factorial

Exercise:
Prove that (n + 1)! - n! = n(n!) for any n $\ge$ 1

Given Answer:

I will skip the basic step since I understand that part.

(n + 2)! - (n + 1)! = (n + 1)!(n + 2) - n!(n + 1) **I understand this line** 
**But, I don't understand starting at this next line** 

= n(n + 1)! + 2(n + 1)! - n(n!) - n!
= n(n + 1)! + (n + 1)! - n(n!) + (n + 1)! - n! 
= n(n + 1)! + (n + 1)! - n(n!) + n(n!) 
= n(n + 1)! + (n + 1)! 
= (n + 1)!(n + 1)

If anyone can help me to understand this then that would be great!

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Is any body aware of any good tutorials that show examples of solving factorials by induction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(n+2)! = (n+2)(n+1)! = n(n+1)! + 2(n+1)!$, by the distributive property.

---

The inductive step would be to assume that $(n + 1)! - n! = n(n!) $ holds for some $n > 1$.

We then want to show that $\color{blue}{(n+2)!} -\color{red}{(n+1)!} = (n+1)(n+1)!$

We begin by rearranging...

$$\color{blue}{(n+2)!} -\color{red}{(n+1)!} =\color{blue}{(n+2)}(n+1)! - \color{red}{(n+1)}(n!)$$
$$=\color{blue}{n}(n+1)! + \color{green}{2}(n+1)! - \color{red}{n}(n!) -\color{red}{1}(n!) $$

Notice that I changed the blue $2$ into green. That is so we can have $$=\color{black}{n}(n+1)! + \color{green}{1}(n+1)! - \color{black}{n}(n!) + \color{green}{1}(n+1)! -\color{black}{1}(n!) $$

The two terms on the right are $(n+1)! - n!$, which equals $\color{red}{n(n!)}$ by hypothesis. So now we have...
$$=\color{black}{n}(n+1)! + \color{black}{1}(n+1)! - \color{black}{n}(n!) + \color{red}{n(n!)} $$

The two terms on the right cancel. $$=\color{blue}{n}(n+1)! + \color{blue}{1}(n+1)!$$

Using the distributive property (factoring out a $(n+1)!$, if you will) ...
$$\color{blue}{(n+1)}(n+1)!$$

So the claim holds for $n+1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see that now but, what happened to the 2 in the next line and, is n! = (n + 1)! - n!? Hmm, is 2(n + 1)! equal to both of the (n + 1)! in the next line?

Comment: The $2(n+1)!$ splits into two terms of $(n+1)!$ in the next line. You would do well to write all this out and use colored pencils to keep track of the various terms/factors.

Comment: Thanks again. I have copied your answer and made some notes for it also.

Comment: Hi again. Am I correct in assuming that (n + 1)! - n! is equal to n(n!). If this is correct do you mind showing how this is worked out? I am sorry for all of the questions but I am really struggling with this exercise. The study guide I have does not really show a lot of work on solving factorials with induction.

Comment: Let me figure out how to color code my answer and I'll add an update.

Comment: Hey, that is great. I'll take this and make sure I understand it. Thanks for all of you help.